# Selectively indexing subdomains

Tags: python, seo, indexing, robots.txt, googlebot

I am working on Web application, which allows users to create their own webapp in turn. For each new webapp created by my application I Assign a **new Subdomain**.
e.g. subdomain1.xyzdomain.com, subdomain2.xyzdomain.com etc.

All these Webapps are *stored in Database* and are served by a python script (say 
**default_script.py**) kept in `/var/www/`. 
Till now, I have blocked Search Engine indexing for directory ( `/var/www/` ) using **robots.txt**. Which essentially blocks indexing of my all scripts including **default_script.py** as well as content served for multiple webapps using that **default_script.py** script.

But now I want that some of those subdomains should be indexed.

After searching for a while I was able to figure out a way to block indexing of my scripts by explicitly specifing them in **robots.txt**

But I am still doubtful about the following:

1. Will blocking the my **default_script.py** from indexing also block indexing of all content that are served from **default_script.py**. If yes then if I let it index, will **default_script.py** start showing up in search results also.
2. How can I allow indexing of some of the Subdomains seletively.

   Ex:  Index *subdomain1.xyzdomain.com* but NOT *subdomain2.xyzdomain.com*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The search engine should not care what script generates the pages. Just so long as the pages generated by the webapps are indexed you should be fine.

Second question:

You should create a separate robots.txt per subdomain. That is when robots.txt is fetched from a particular subdomain, return a robots.txt file that pertains to that sudomain only. So if you want the subdomain indexed, has that robots file allow all. If you don't want it indexed, have the robots file deny all.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael, This answered my first question. Do you have any idea about second one?

Comment: So, Do you mean for a subdomain robots.txt will be served from database rather then from /var/www/. Because I have seen in my case robots.txt is fetched from /var/www/ rather then Database, which I am using to block my script files.

Comment: There are lots of ways to accomplish this. You could create separate file directories for each subdomain that each contain specialized versions of robots.txt. Or you could do a server-side rewrite of feteches for robots.txt to subdomain.robots.txt. Or you could serve them from a database as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize the discussion,

This is how my `.htaccess` file looks which is kept in `/var/www/` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rule Below allows using different robots.txt for subdomain1.
RewriteCond     %{HTTP_HOST}           ^subdomain1.xyzdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)robots.txt        subdomain1-robots.txt [L]

# This rule is applicable on rest of subdomains and xyzdomain.com.
RewriteRule     ^robots.txt$           robots.txt [L]

# This rule allow serving content from default_script.py for files other then robots.txt
RewriteRule     .                      default_script.py
```